# Mysql select from two tables where first table field = second table field%

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

1. table1 has a row id='12345'
2. table2 has a row where the id = that of table1 with added chars, e.g.,

   table2.id = '12345-678qt'

table2 may have more than one id starting with '12345-' with different ending chars.

Yes, there is always a dash after table1's id that could be used in the query.

I need to get some data from both tables, say

```sql
    SELECT  table1.id, table1.field9,

        table2.id, table2.fieldZ

    FROM table1 and table2 

    WHERE (

      table1.id=table2.id's characters before the dash

      OR

      table1.field1 = 'abcde'

    )

    AND table2.dataB='something'

    ORDER BY table1.datefield DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"I appreciate this forum"* [so] is very much *not* a forum, it is a Q&A website, and closer to a wiki than a discussion website (discussion is explicitly off topic here). Please don't treat it like a forum, you will likely have a poor experience.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL translation of:

- "*table1 and table2 WHERE*" is `table1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON`
- "*table2.id's characters before the dash*" is `SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.id, '-', 1)`

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT  table1.id, table1.field9,
        table2.id, table2.fieldZ
FROM       table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
        ON (table1.id = SUBSTRING(table2.id, '-', 1) OR table1.field1 = 'abcde')
       AND table2.dataB = 'something'
ORDER BY table1.datefield DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

This doesn't grant that your query will work if it's written like this. My fixes will remove the current errors inside your query. For more troubleshooting with a sql fiddle link, please provide tables and I'll be happy to help.

Check the official documentation about the [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) operation and the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function at the corresponding links.

Comment: Thank YOU! I knew there were errors and glad you cleaned it up.

Comment: If this solution solves your problem, mark your problem as answered so that it will save other devs' time for yet unsolved problem. @DeeMinzen